# How to disable or enable option 97(pxe-client-id) in DHCP?

Tags: linux-kernel, dhcp, rhel7, ipxe

**[Background]**
As per below technical nodes, there is some improvement done in DHCP. 
RHEL 6.7 Technical Notes

> Enhancement
>   - BZ#1058674
>       With this update, the dhcpd daemon is able to handle dhcp option 97 - Client Machine Identifier (pxe-client-id), 
>       so it is now possible to statically allocate an IP address for a particular client based on its identifier, sent in option 97.
>   example:
>           host pixi {   option pxe-client-id 0 00:11:22:33:44:

**[Problem]**
In previous DHCP package (dhcp-4.1.1-43.P1) in RHEL6.6, we always received same IP address for adding new network interface with in existing network interface in case pxe calls through my Linux system reboot.
In RHEL 6.10, the DHCP package(dhcp-4.1.1-61.P1) always received different IP address for adding new network interface with in existing network interface.

It seems different IP is assigned due to this identifier. So, we are checking a options to disable sending of pxe-client-id in pxe client configuration.

**[question]**
Is there any way to disable or enable option 97(pxe-client-ID) in dhcp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems same thing has been reported in RHEL7 link.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2158491